# angular-cli@webpack with primeng 404 issues

Tags: node.js, angular, http-status-code-404, angular-cli, primeng

I get the following errors in a starter project with angular2, angular-cli@webpack and primeng. The only ui component from PrimeNG is a dropdown which renders and it has its values but no css theme is applied ever.(see errors below in regards to CSS). I am not sure why I get this error and have spent countless hours with no result so I am at a loss at this point. Component was generated with ng command and ng serve runs the web server. Anybody any idea? I also have tried both node.js 6.5.0 and 4.5.0 (switching and managing them with nvm).

Any help is appreciated deeply.

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404
>   (Not Found)
>   http://localhost:3000/node_modules/primeng/resources/primeng.min.css
>   Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404
>   (Not Found)
>   http://localhost:3000/src/app/resources/css/font-awesome-4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css
>   Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404
>   (Not Found)
>   http://localhost:3000/node_modules/primeui/primeui-ng-all.min.css
>   Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404

By the way now I posted the code in: https://github.com/GregHila/primeng-angular-cli.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Under the `src/` there should be a file `styles.css`. I think you can import the styles here.

Eg.:

```
@import '../node_modules/primeng/resources/primeng.min.css';
```

The other way is to mention them in the `angular-cli.json` file in the `styles` array.

Comment: Switched to use css rather than scss and cleaned `angular-cli.json` styles array except for `styles.css`. Then in `styles.css` imported the following and also removed them from the index.html which now imports only styles.css but now even the theme stops working.



  @import '../node_modules/primeng/resources/themes/bootstrap/theme.css';
  @import '../node_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css';
  @import '../node_modules/primeng/resources/primeng.min.css';

Comment: Your `index.html` shouldn't import `styles.css` explicitly. AFAIK this is managed by angular-cli. Anyway, do you really have the primeng directories present in your node_modules dir?

Comment: Yes, I do have primeng in node_modules and also primeui came in with it when installed primeng

Comment: Found this post: http://forum.primefaces.org/viewtopic.php?f=35&t=46809&p=146048&hilit=dropdown#p146048   and put the imports in styles.css and I see no get errors anymore and no invalid character but still the dropdown looks screwed     
                                                                
    `@import "../node_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css";
    @import "../node_modules/primeng/resources/themes/afterdark/theme.css";
    @import "../node_modules/primeng/components/dropdown/dropdown.css";
   @import "../node_modules/primeng/components/galleria/galleria.css";`

Comment: A wild guess: try to search you `node_modules/primeng` and `node_modules/primeui` for `primeui-ng-all.min.css` or `primeui-all.min.css`. Just link it.

Comment: Found both files you suggest and imported them one by one in styles.css and the end result is that the theme stops working and get the following error in console:                                                                                                   'ERROR in ./~/primeui/images/loadingbar.gif
Module parse failed: C:\development\slap-ui\node_modules\primeui\images\loadingbar.gif Unexpected character '?' (1:6)'.               What's the purpose of primeui?  even though it dependencies sections has nothing, I am thinking maybe I need Jquery UI to get that to work.

Comment: You have stumbled upon an angular-cli bug which affects those GIF files. You need to locate both of them in the `node_modules` dir and replace each by a text file file named exactly the same (including the .gif extension) but which would contain a space or a newline only...

Comment: Added my tryout app in in github: https://github.com/GregHila/primeng-angular-cli

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the webpack branch, then `node_modules` will not exist in the served directory. You will have to import the libraries you want to use, which will cause webpack to bundle them for you. Alternatively modify `apps[0].scripts` and `apps[0].styles` properties of `angular-cli.json` like in https://github.com/angular/angular-cli#global-library-installation.

Comment: I tried the second option: modifying `angular-cli.json` and theme appears working now but still I get the 404 error for all 4 css and one js library which is even stranger. I am not sure what 'import' you are referring.

Comment: By the way I am using the webpack branch.

Comment: `Webpack` is a module loader, it automatically figures out what modules to serve based on what modules you imported. By using `webpack`, `angular-cli` can abstract a lot of the manual process of including external libraries away. If you have not used imports before then I would suggest reading up about es6 modules http://exploringjs.com/es6/ch_modules.html.

Comment: I am familiar with the modules but I was confused by the statement: "You will have to import the libraries you want to use, which will cause webpack to bundle them for you. Alternatively modify apps[0].scripts". If you are referring to imports within angular components which I already do, and also I am importing the modules in app.module.ts , are you then implying that once I do those I don't need to worry about css and js files as webpack will include the module already? My confusion is about what import is describing in this context, maybe an example would help. Thanks for your patience.

Comment: "I don't need to worry about css and js files as webpack will include the module already?" -  As soon as you import an external module (and use it within your application?), webpack should include it in it's bundle. That is how angular-cli has setup webpack. This should work for css imports as well. For a webpack only example: https://github.com/shanewilson/react-webpack-example

Answer (score 0):

Seems like 1.0.0-beta.11-webpack.9-4 has also fixed the bug